# angular + angular-google-maps + codepen = not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

i cant seem to get my codepen working.  its using angular-google-maps.

any help would be very appreciated.

thanks.

http://codepen.io/0101adm/pen/GZRRBq

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial','ngMessages', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);

app.directive('mreTest', function(){
return {
template: "<div><ui-gmap-google-map center='center' zoom='zoom' control='control'></ui-gmap-google-map></div>",
restrict: 'E',
replace: true,
scope: true,
link: function($scope, element, attributes) {
  $scope.center = { latitude: 45, longitude: -73 };

  $scope.zoom = 8;

  $scope.$watch(() => {
            return $scope.control;
        },
        (newValue) => {
            alert(newValue);
        });
}
};
});
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/use). First thing it says is that if you're not using a package manager you'll need lodash.js and angular-simple-logger.js, neither of which you have included in your codepen. Also, "It is HIGHLY recommended that you check the package.json and or bower.json file for the current dependencies and their versions!" - excerpt from the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are injecting ng-material but you are not referencing the related references.
Also load the reference for loadsh.js , it will work.

Here is the working [`CodePen`](http://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/eZYNoG) Link

Comment: thanks for your comment.  ive removed ng-material and added lodash and it seems to still not be working.  also, checked your codepen link and the directive did not load.

Comment: i am using chrome and it does not have any issue! please upvote if it has helped you

Comment: must be something with my chrome.  firefox should be enough.  thanks.